# scala build tools (sbt) and artefacts like intelliJ

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, artifact

I am trying to create a Java artefact with sbt, in IntelliJ IDEA you have this option in the menu and you can easily create artifects and add arbitrary files to said artefacts.

The question is, how could you do this in sbt commandline?

What I want to do is, create a simple compiled java artifact (using the scala language that is), and also add an arbitrary file to it, the reason for this is that this jar will be used by some other tool which expects a .yml file to be present within the jar (artifact).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the file (`.yml`) into `src/main/resources` and do `sbt package`.

In `target/scala-2.1x` you'll find a jar with the file in the root.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Package.html